# Netbeans IDE (12.2): Syntax error with PHP 8.0 constructor promotion

Tags: php, netbeans, syntax-error, settings, php-8

I was messing around with the new `Attributes` (a.k.a. "Annotations") in `PHP` and I have this annoying issue, that `Netbeans 12.2` does not recognize my valid `PHP 8.0` code. I have tested it on my local machine and also here: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/.

The code seems to compile just fine though. Other `PHP 8.0` functions do work in the IDE, too (... well, it's the same binary). Can I fix or rather mute this error somehow? Because it marks my whole workspace as erroneous.

```php
<?php

#[Routing('hello')]
class A {
    public function __construct() {}
}

#[Routing('world')]
class B { 
    public function __construct() {}
}

class Route {
    public function __construct(public string $name) {}
}

#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class Routing {
    private static $routes = [];
    
    public function __construct(public string $name) {
        static::add(new Route($name));
    }
    
    private function add($route) {
        static::$routes[] = $route;
    }
    
    public static function getRoutes() {
        return static::$routes;
    }
}

$rA = new ReflectionClass(A::class);
$rB = new ReflectionClass(B::class);
$attributeA = $rA->getAttributes()[0];
$attributeB = $rB->getAttributes()[0];
$a = $attributeA->newInstance();
$b = $attributeB->newInstance();
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
print_r($a::getRoutes());
```

[image: idea-syntax]
[image: idea-error-hint]

I guess this is a bug. I could use the old syntax, but this is just a workaround in case I cannot find a solution.

---

**Question:**

How can I get rid of this error message or is there something that I am missing in my code, that should be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note to future readers: this answer was written on 15th Jan 2021*

The best advice is probably "be patient": PHP 8.0.0 was released on 26th Nov 2020, and while NetBeans 12.2 (released on 7th December 2020) [includes some PHP 8 support](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb122/index.html#_php_javascript) there's still [an open issue tracking further changes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4443).

In particular, support for Constructor Property Promotion is [being worked on in this PR](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/2674), which is currently labelled as targeting release 12.3, which [should be complete in the second half of February 2021](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Release+Schedule).

Until then, you'll either have to live with your IDE thinking your source is invalid, or switch to a different IDE (PhpStorm included the necessary changes in [version 2020.3, released 3rd December 2020](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-release/), if you can afford that).

*As an aside, if anyone working on the PHP functionality of NetBeans sees this, you might want to update [this marketing page which is the top hit for "netbeans php"](https://netbeans.org/features/php/) and currently brags about its cutting edge support for PHP 5.6!*

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I might just wait a bit. I just found it odd, that they support some features and not all in a major update. I was not aware that has been only a few months since the release. I was on some of this pages aswell, but I should have looked into the schedule. Anyway, it would have been great if we could just ignore such warnings in this case - and some of them you can mute under "preferences > editor > hints".

Comment: @F.Muller I'm no expert, so there might be a way, but until 8.0 that syntax was completely nonsensical, so there's probably not a specific error that it's raising, just a general "Huh? This doesn't look like PHP you fool!"

Comment: Is there a way to stop Netbeans from validating code with PHP8? I have a class called Match in an app built  for PHP7, but Netbeans 12.3 shows all occurences of Match as an error since it is a keyword in PHP8. I have set my php version as 7.4 in project properties but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @AhmedShefeer That sounds like a new question, which should be posted to a new page.